# Mui Select Not Rendering with Array properly

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I am trying to use the MUI Select (with a chip) in a list. IE Multiple Selects based on some data.  This also might be a bit difficult to explain.

I have the ability to add and or delete/remove an individual select.

```js
function SelectTest({}: Props) {
    const [selectArray, setSelectArray] = useState([{name: "Select 1", value: 1},{name: "Select 2", value: 2},{name: "Select 3", value: 3}])

  const handleAddSelect = () => {
    setSelectArray((prev) => {
    return [{name: "New select", value: 1}, ...prev];
   })
  }

  const handleDeleteSelect = (id: number) => {
    let temp = [...selectArray];
  
    console.log(id)
    temp.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(temp)
    setSelectArray(temp)
  }



  return (
    <Container
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: 1,
      }}
    >
      <List>
        {selectArray.map((item, index) => (
            <SelectCard id={index} key={index} onDelete={handleDeleteSelect} value={item.value}/>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Button onClick={handleAddSelect}>Add Select</Button>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default SelectTest
```

And The Child Component

```js
type Props = {
  onDelete: Function,
  id: number,
  value: number
};

const values = [
  {
    label: "Item 1",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    label: "Item 2",
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    label: "Item 3",
    value: 3,
  },
  {
    label: "Item 4",
    value: 4,
  },
];

export default function SelectCard(props: Props) {
    const [item, setItem] = useState<number>(props.value)


    const handleItemChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof item>) => {
        const {
            target: { value },
          } = event;
          console.log(value);
          setItem(value as number);
    }


  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader
        title={"Select item " + props.id}
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: colorConfigs.sidebar.bg,
          color: colorConfigs.sidebar.color,
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-evenly",
        }}
        action={
          <IconButton
            onClick={() => {
              props.onDelete(props.id);
            }}
            sx={{
              color: colorConfigs.sidebar.color,
              alignSelf: "flex-end",
            }}
          >
            <DeleteOutline />
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
      <CardContent
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "row",
          gap: 1,
          pt: 2,
        }}
      >
        <FormControl
          sx={{
            flex: 1,
          }}
        >
          <InputLabel>{props.id}</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={item}
            onChange={handleItemChange}
            input={
              <OutlinedInput
                label="Item"
              />
            }
          >
            {values.map((item, index) => (
              <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
                {item.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I get odd behavior when I add an item, but I feel it is all related.  The main issue is when I "Delete" a select.  In my actual app I am lifting the state of the values (of the selects) up, and I can see the correct values and object are being deleted (via console).  But the rendered items are still showing the old values.

It looks like it is just removing the last item.

For example, if I add 3 selects, Set them all to different values (1 = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3), and delete item 2.  My prints indicate it is splicing the correct item,  but I visually see 2 selects with the values of 1 = 1, and 2 = 2.

[image: Before Delete]

[image: After I Delete Item 2]

This is the console after I "Delete" Select 2. I clearly Deleted Select 2, but as you can see from the above images. "Item 2" is still in the select as the selected value, I would expect Item 3 to be the value.

[image: Console after Delete]

Comment: You shouldn't be using `index` as the `key` for `SelectCard`. After the delete, "Select 3" will take on the index of "Select 2" and then will use the state in `SelectCard` for the deleted "Select 2". If you use the `name` instead of the `index` for the `key`, it should improve the behavior.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, thank you.  Never would have thought about that.  But it makes perfect sense.  I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @RyanCogswell commented, instead of using a numerical "index" for the key for the element array items, I used the "name" of the object which is more unique.  I am sure a random value would work well for me as well.

```js
type Props = {}

function SelectTest({}: Props) {
    const [selectArray, setSelectArray] = useState([{name: "Select 1", value: 1},{name: "Select 2", value: 2},{name: "Select 3", value: 3}])

  const handleAddSelect = () => {
    setSelectArray((prev) => {
    return [{name: "New select", value: 1}, ...prev];
   })
  }

  const handleDeleteSelect = (id: number) => {
    let temp = [...selectArray];
  
    console.log(id)
    temp.splice(id, 1);
    console.log(temp)
    setSelectArray(temp)
  }



  return (
    <Container
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        gap: 1,
      }}
    >
      <List>
        {selectArray.map((item, index) => (
            <SelectCard id={index} key={item.name} onDelete={handleDeleteSelect} value={item.value}/>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Button onClick={handleAddSelect}>Add Select</Button>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default SelectTest
```